# manyfoot, bidi packages and footnotes on the same line

Tags: footnotes, polyglossia, arabic

Writing a book of probability in arabic, which is a Right-to-Left language, I need to write Left-to-Right footnotes for  footnotes with english words. I do this (for main language arabic and other language english, with the command

```
\def\efootnote#1{%
\begin{english}\footnote{\LR{#1}}\end{english}
}
```

Now I want to write several small footnotes on the same line, which is possible in english mode by using the package manyfoot, but I want it from left to right, like my command \efootnote. Who has any idea for doing this ?

I post a minimal example, and some comments after...

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Traditional Arabic}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}

\usepackage[para]{manyfoot}
\newfootnote[para]{B}

\textwidthfootnoterule

\def\efootnote#1{%
\begin{english}\footnote{\LR{#1}}\end{english}
}

\newcounter{footnoteB}
\newcommand{\footnoteB}{%
\stepcounter{footnoteB}
\Footnotemark\thefootnoteB \FootnotetextB\thefootnoteB}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\roman{footnoteB}
}%

\begin{document}
\LR{Let\efootnote{First footnote} footnotes\footnoteB{\LR{Second footnote}} aligned\footnoteB{\LR{Third footnote}}}
\end{document}
```

which gives after compilation
[image]

```
I tried for example the command, analogous to \footnoteB

\def\efootnoteB#1{%
\begin{english}\footnoteB{\LR{#1}}\end{english}
}
```

which writes also the footnotes from right to left, and I want it from left to right... 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Like the commands \LTRfootnote and \RTLfootnote, by analogy, I want something like \LTRfootnoteB

Comment: In this case there is a long line -- how to return it to he default line above the footnote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer, inspired from some work in www.parsilatex.com 
 While we replace the definition of the footnote by this one :

```
\usepackage[para*]{manyfoot}

\SetFootnoteHook{\setLTR}
    \DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}
\makeatletter
\let\c@footnoteB\c@footnote
\makeatother
\let\Hfootnote\footnoteB
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\roman{footnote}}
```

and the same file gives what I want, i.e. "horizontal aligning" of footnotes, from left to right, in arabic mode. I give the compilation

[image]

Enjoy